# Telerik for WinForms gridview slow rendering

Tags: winforms, telerik, telerik-grid

we are testing Telerik radcontrols for a desktop application development. Until now we are very satisfied with the product but there is one issue that is driving us nuts.

We have a gridview with 3 levels of hierarchy and 3 child gridviews on the 1st level. Something like this:

[image]

The main grid has 28 visible columns, with lot of customization and validating rules inside. There are 6 columns with a button inside to trigger different actions. There are 4 columns with images on them and several others just different colors with different meanings for the users. Child gridviews each one has around 5 visible columns, also with customization, buttons, images, etc.

Initially we detected that loading of the data was way to slow. So now we load first level at first and the lower hierarchy data is loaded on demand, when the user wants to see what's inside each row. By doing this the loading speed of the grid improved.

Now the bottleneck is on the gridview rendering. I have asked already on Telerik forums but the answers given does not help too much. I found some users asking about the same but none with a 100% satisfactory answer. As for example: [Self referencing grid](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview/self-referencing-grid.aspx)

So my question is: does anyone has faced similar problem? How it was solved, if there is a solution? Nevermind how complicated it is, we need to drop the loading times, right now around 10-15 seconds on each grid click, wich is unbearable.

Comment: this typically happen by using thirdy part controls, when you pass the limits there is nothing to do but change the design

Comment: Yes, I know the issues on using third part controls. But these controls are helping us a lot by cutting of lot of development time on controls customization that otherwise would take many hours to accomplish.

Comment: I would suggest to use the Telerik support ticketing system to contact the tech team since this is the best place to get adequate support.

Comment: Already done, as I'm using an evaluation version I only get support for one month and after that I can get or not support. Indeed I have asked other questions there and received answers. But for this issue in particular they do not provide a clear answer or solution. Other users with same issue are dealing with it using different approaches. For now none is good for us.